# Test that Django sends the e-mail for password reset

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-email

Good morning,
I would like to test that Django properly sends an e-mail for password reset as I have customised the routes. However I get a `<HttpResponseForbidden status_code=403, "text/html">` and the e-mail is not implemented when I test it.
Here are the main features:

- url :
  `path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="customer/password_reset_form.html", email_template_name="customer/password_reset_e-mail.html", success_url="done/"),`
- test method:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
class PasswordResetTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username="user",
                    email="user@mail.com",
                    password="pwd")

    def test_send_mail(self):
        request = self.factory.post('/customer/password_reset', {'email': 'user@mail.com'})
        response = auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view()(request)
        self.assertTemplateUsed('password_reset_e-mail.html')
        print(response)
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```

Throught the print command, I can see an **error 403** and that the **outbox is empty**.
I just cannot find proper documentation to build a test on this very part of Django.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Are you sure your authen work? You can change to APITestCase and force authen

Comment: Yes, the authentication works for other tests.
After additional checks I came to the conclusion that, when one use the django default forms, during the test phase, they get back to their default routes (`/registration/etc`) and the changes one has introduced in the url are skipped.
I believe that the solution may be to use mixins.